# Can we somehow change the url in addressbar after dispatching request from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I am having a weird problem here, and I am really stuck, need to get this work badly.

so i have a page say index.jsp with a link say "a href=servlet?id=10". when I click on this link it will go to doGet() on my servlet and here is the code in my servlet.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
                 String action = request.getParameter("id");
                  // search database and create an arraylist
                        if(//user logged in)
                        address = "s/results.jsp";
                        else   
                        address = "results.jsp";
                   // set arraylist in session object
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
                dispatcher.forward(request,response);
     }
```

So the above code works fine but after request forwarding, my browser shows the url as

http://localhost/project/servlet?id=10.

I don't want the above url as i am forwarding to two different jsp's based on the user login status one is in 's' folder and other is outside of that.
if user is logged in then i forward to 's/results.jsp' and if user is not logged in i am forwarding to 'results.jsp'.

in case of s/results.jsp i am accessing resources like images and scripts from outside of 's' folder by using ../ in the results.jsp.

as url is not changing to s/results.jsp , i am unable to access the resources with '../'
and as i am using jsp pagination , when i click next the url is changing to s/results.jsp
and in that case i am able to access resources using ../

one solution in my mind is to copy all resources in s folder , but that would increase 
redundancy.

one other solution in my mind is to create two different servlets for two jsp's 
but i don't know where to put the  servlet so that it can access resources outside of s folder with ../

is their any other good way i can do the task..

I have tried to find information about this but haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have basically instructed your webbrowser to send a request to exactly that URL. The forward does not change the URL. It is entirely server side. Apart from using `response.sendRedirect()` instead -which would trash the current request, including all of its attributes, and create a brand new request on the given URL-, you could also just change your link to `<a href="results?id=10">`, or when the user is logged in, to `<a href="s/results?id=10">`.

```xml
<a href="${user.loggedin ? 's/' : ''}results?id=10">
```

Finally alter the servlet mapping accordingly so that it get invoked on those URLs.

```xml
<url-pattern>/results</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/s/results</url-pattern>
```

You'll only miss the JSP extension. But JSPs which are to be used by a dispatcher belong in `/WEB-INF` folder anyway so that they cannot be viewed by the enduser directly without invoking the servlet first. You also end up with nicer URLs.

Comment: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'url-pattern'. No child element is 
 expected at this point. 
  eclipse is showing this error when i am adding these lines in web.xml  
  <url-pattern>/results</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/s/results</url-pattern>

Comment: Uh, did you put it in the `<servlet-mapping>` the usual way? You should not put it in random place. It was intented to replace your old `<url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
String action = request.getParameter("id");
// search database and create an arraylist
    if(//user logged in)
        address = "s/results.jsp";
    else   
        address = "results.jsp";
    // set arraylist in session object
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
 }
```

in the above code instead of using request dispatcher,

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
            dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

we can try with

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/address");
```